# Domestic uses of half humans

Tags: fauna, trans-humanism

I am writing a future world in which scientific studies in the field of eugenics are flourishing to the point that a certain lab is prepared to test on humans. They want to create useful  half humans out of living humans via pseudoscience and handwaving.

This society has gone through a world war basically over the fact that the world has been mostly wrecked with global warming and everything else. Decades after the war, the climate and much of the earth has been restored. The main focus of this society is now raising the standard of living for everyone.
These hybrids need to be useful at one of these:
- energy generation 
- building
- food production 
- production of necessities

I am considering spiders at the moment due to their silk spinning abilities. They would be useful for creating clothes, and with the help of the mystical resource known as handwavium, sentient spider people would be able to weave clothes, sheets, etc. Are there any other animals that have useful abilities if combined with humans?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help], there you will see that the sort of question you posted is not fitting our standards. We want well defined questions, giving a clear problem with a solution which can be rated. You are asking for a list of abilities with no way to pick the best one.

Comment: The more convenient and logical way would be to do this via microorganisms. If you want to engineer a lifeforms to produce something for you, bacteria are the easiest and most efficient way. If another animal can already do it, the rational thing is to use that animal. Your approach is illogical, that means mad science and ok, but if your world doesn't follow logical rules and basic economic thinking, this becomes arbitrary and anything makes equally no sense

Comment: Why would you need _people_. That brings up a lot of legal and ethical baggage regarding human rights and working conditions. Rather, selectively breed spiders for comparatively long life, say 5 years. Implant a control chip in their nervous system to weave the way they are instructed. Feed them liquefied mush, so they don't have to hunt.

Comment: What you need is to breed them with an animal which either hibernates or eats once a month so that the world’s wildlife replenishes. Being half human they can do whatever else you need through intellect.